# ¿Cómo sumar columnas en función de otras columnas?

Tags: r

Tengo una tabla con ~13 mll de filas y +150 columnas.

Necesito sumar los valores de las columnas siguientes a las que cumplen una condición

Sumar los valores de las columnas siguientes en las que `cod_n == 89`:

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he logrado establecer el `df$eval` con:

```
df$eval<- apply(df[,cods], 1, function(r) any(r == 89))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `apply` puedes resolverlo en una sola sentencia, por ejemplo con un `dataframe` similar al de tu ejemplo:

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(x1=sample(85:95, 10),
                 x2=sample(88:90, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 x3=sample(85:95, 10),
                 x4=sample(85:95, 10),
                 x5=sample(85:95, 10)
                 )

df$eval <- apply(df, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {sum(x[which(x==89)+1], na.rm = TRUE)})
df       

   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 eval
1  88 89 87 86 94   87
2  89 89 90 93 92  179
3  85 90 86 85 90    0
4  86 90 85 88 89    0
5  95 90 94 92 95    0
6  92 89 88 89 85  173
7  91 88 93 94 91    0
8  93 89 91 90 93   91
9  87 90 89 95 88   95
10 90 90 92 91 86    0
```

Comentarios:

- con `MARGIN=1` indicamos que la selección será por fila
- con `FUN` establecemos la función a aplicar a cada fila, en este caso `sum(x[which(x==89)+1], na.rm = TRUE)`, es decir, retornamos la suma de cualquier celda siguiente a la que contiene el 89.

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tu respuesta.. y si tengo que sumar las columnas que están siguientes al 89 (como en el ejemplo de la pregunta inicial) como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: @INDGER, entendí mal tu pregunta, acabo de reformular mi respuesta. Lo que deberías definir cual sería el comportamiento en caso de tener dos `89` contiguos. En el caso de mi respuesta uno de los `89` se sumarían.

Comment: después de un buen tiempo. tengo una respuesta a tu pregunta de qué hacer con dos ```89``` contiguos, en este caso no deberían sumarse ya que en mi ejemplo, una columna representa código y la otra un valor. por lo tanto deberán evaluarse las columnas de dos en dos, en el caso del ejemplo deberán evaluarse solo las columnas ```x1, x3, x5``` y las que se deben sumar serían ```x2, x4, x6```. por lo tanto en la primera fila la respuesta es 0 y en la segunda la respuesta es 89.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido/a INDGER! Si no entiendo mal la pregunta la idea es sumar por filas todos aquellos datos en los que la columna anterior tiene el valor 89. Al menos eso es lo que se ve en el ejemplo. Es decir, según mi interpretación no se trata de sumar todos los valores una fila en la que aparece un `89`, sino sumar solamente aquellos que están inmediatamente a la derecha de un `89`.

<strike>Es algo complicado hacerlo con `apply`, porque esta función trabaja por filas o por columnas y en este caso necesitamos información de ambas.</strike> La solución que encontré es usando `data.table` y `tidyverse`:

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(x1=sample(89:91, 10, replace = TRUE),  #Aumento la probabilidad de 89
                 x2=sample(85:95, 10),
                 x3=sample(89:91, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 x4=sample(90:100, 10))

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) #para transpose()
df %>% 
  data.table::transpose() %>% #pq `purrr` tiene una función con el mismo nombre. 
  gather() %>%
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(filtrado = ifelse(lag(value)==89, value, NA)) %>% 
  summarise(suma_filtrada = sum(filtrado, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(key = str_remove(key, "V")) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(key)) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

Que da este resultado en el que se cumplen las condiciones:

```
   x1 x2 x3  x4 suma_filtrada
1  90 89 89  91           180
2  90 91 90  98             0
3  89 93 89  90           183
4  89 90 89  93           183
5  90 92 91  97             0
6  89 88 90  94            88
7  90 86 89  99            99
8  89 87 91  95            87
9  91 94 90 100             0
10 90 95 89  96            96
```

## Explicación

No es una solución elegante y no sé que tal escalará para una base de datos grandes, ya que hace muchísimas transformaciones. Seguramente hay alguna aproximación más eficiente.

El primer paso es transponer el data.frame, para que las filas sean columnas y viceversa. De ese modo lograré más adelante operar por filas del data.frame original.

A esa estructura la "estiro" con gather, de modo de tener cada (ex) fila como un par de claves y valores. Posteriormente agrupo por claves.

Dentro de cada grupo puedo aplico un `ifelse` que pasa a `NA` a todos los valores **no** antecedidos por un `89` (eso hace `lag`), es decir, los que no me interesa sumar.

Después hago una sumatoria imputando 0 a los `NA` con `na.rm = T`. Con esto ya están los valores, solo que están desordenados porque al ser `key` una cadena de caracteres, `V10` está antes de `V2`. Por eso el paso de eliminar la `V` en key y ordenar sobre valores numéricos restantes.

Finalmente "pego" es columna al data.frame original.

Es un código muy complicado y no me gustaría ser quién le de mantenimiento, pero funciona.

> Pregunta a INDGER ¿Qué se debería hacer si un 89 sigue a otro 89 en la misma fila? Este es el caso en la fila 1 del ejemplo de datos. La solución que propongo suma los dos `89`, pero quizás no sea el comportamiento deseado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @mpaladino, voy a probarlo en la base de datos completa y te comento que tal funciona .. respecto a tu pregunta: es muy poco probable que existan 2 números 89 seguidos, pues el 89 es un código y el siguiente es un valor que representa una cantidad en pesos, que es la que debo sumar.

Answer (score 0):

Otra aproximación es con un bucle, en el que pasamos por cada filas "preguntado" si la anterior tiene un `89` y regresando `NA` cuando no es así. Eso lo vamos guardando fila por fila en una matriz. Después se hacen sumatorias de cada fila y con eso se obtiene el vector `eval`.

```
sumar_despues_de_x <- function(datos, valor)
{
vec <- matrix(ncol = ncol(datos), nrow = nrow(datos))  #Predefino la matriz
for (i in 2:ncol(df)) 
  {
   vec[,i] <- ifelse(datos[,i-1]==valor, datos[,i], NA)  #Retengo sólo los valores posteriores a 89
  }
  rowSums(vec, na.rm = TRUE)  #Saco un vector con las sumas de filas de la matriz filtrada
}
```

Que se podría usar así:

```
df$eval <- sumar_despues_de_x (df, 89)
```

En este caso creo que un bucle sería mejor opción.